# "Sharing Git credentials with your container" doesn't work

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

## What I did

1. set the git config globally.

```
(local) $ git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
(local) $ git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

2. Remote-Container: rebuild Container
3. Git commit

```
(Remote-Container) $ git commit -m hogehoge
```

## Result

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'root@aaaaaaaaaaa.(none)')
```

## Ref

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_sharing-git-credentials-with-your-container

Comment: Run those commands in the docker build file?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, it will work.
But, the docs said "The extension will automatically copy your local .gitconfig file into the container on startup so you should not need to do this in the container itself."

Comment: But you're making the changes to global, not the local `.gitconfig` file?

Comment: Yes, I could check by the below command.
```
$ git config --global --list
user.email=hoge@example.com
user.name=hoge
```

Comment: Why not put the details in the local `.gitconfig` file?

Comment: Because the document says, it syncs automatically global .gitconfig. But, exactly using git config local is enough as a permanent solution.

Comment: Not according to the quote you commented. It’s says local `.gitconfig` file. Not the global config.

Comment: Ahh, I got it. Thank you. I thought basically `.gitconfig` is global config. But it was wrong.

Comment: So if you add the details to the `.gitconfig` in the repo does it work?

Comment: No, it doesn't work in my environment. Git doesn't read the project folder's `.gitconfig` file. Git read project folder's `.git/config` or `$HOME/.gitconfig` in the environment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had a similar issue because I was running `git config --global` in `postCreateCommand`. I wanted to change the diff and merge tools in the container. However, my username and password disappeared from my `.gitconfig`. I did not understand the cause yet, but I solved the issue by adding my commands to the `postAttachCommand` instead.

So, in the `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json`, instead of:

```json
{
  ...
  postCreateCommand": "git config --global diff.tool ...",
  ...
}
```

I use:

```json
{
  ...
  postAttachCommand": "git config --global diff.tool ...",
  ...
}
```

I am wondering if your situation is not related. It should be useful to know your `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json`. Still, I hope this information is useful for other users with similar problems.

Comment: I have the exact same issue as @t29mato have, but this answer doesn't related

Answer (score 4):

For me I was using WSL2 on Windows with devcontainers and found that it doesn't copy .gitconf from windows but from the base Linux distro so I had to add the settings there.

So in WSL terminal I did :

```
  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Then these settings were shared with the devcontainer.

Comment: You answer sounds promising, but where is "there"? A little more specificity would be helpful.

Comment: "there" refers to the base linux distro for docker, for me that was Ubuntu so I opened its terminal and did `git config --global user.email "you@example.com"`
  `git config --global user.name "Your Name"` so when devcontainer started it copied these settings from Ubuntu (the base distro for docker)