# Git "Author identity unknown" in VSCode Devcontainer

Tags: git, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

When trying to perform git operations (such as `git commit`) in a vscode devcontainer, the following error is displayed:

```
Author identity unknown

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
```

Is there a way to inherit the git configuration from the host when launching the devcontainer?

Comment: I'm having the same issue - https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/sharing-git-credentials didn't help in my case. Did you find a resolution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had a `git config --global ...` command in the `postCreateCommand` of my `devcontainer.json`:

```json
{
    // ...
    "postCreateCommand": "git config --global --add safe.directory ${containerWorkspaceFolder}",
}
```

After removing it, the `.gitconfig` settings of my host system are transferred correctly to the DevContainer again. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73097009/10839817), it should also be possible to use the `postAttachCommand` property instead.

To me it looks like somehow the container startup and the `postCreateCommand` are kind of fighting against each other because both are using `git config --global ...` commands.

Comment: Yes! The answer that you reference solves it for me. That is, use `postAttachCommand` instead.